# $g(x)=x^2\cdot \log_e(x)$, evaluate $x =\frac{1}{\sqrt(e)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When asked to evaluate $g$ at the point specified above we would get $\dfrac{1}{e} \cdot \log_e(\frac{1}{\sqrt e})$ and that evaluates to some -0.18393... but the correct answer is -1/2e. How does it get simplified to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{e} * \ln ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}) &=& \frac{1}{e} * \ln ( e^{-1/2})\\
&=& \frac{1}{e} * \frac{-1}{2} \ln ( e)\\
&=& \frac{1}{e} * \frac{-1}{2} \\
&=& \frac{-1}{2e} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Answer (score 3):

You did well. The "correct" answer is just written sloppily. It should be 
$$-1/(2e)$$
which evaluates to what you found.

Answer (score 2):

$$g(x)=x^2 \log(x) \implies g\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\right)=\left(\frac 1 {{\sqrt{e}}}\right)^2 \log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\right)=-\frac 1 e\times \log(\sqrt{e})=-\frac 1 e\times\frac 12 \log(e)$$ and, by definition $\log(e)=1$.